# Problem regarding application of chain rule in differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was going through "From Calculus to Cohomology" on reading nice things about said book in Stack exchange posts. However, I have been trumped from the beginning so to speak, with my first halt being the following applications of chain rule and product rule in the following image at this link:

I may be being more than a tad slow here, but would somebody kindly explain the two steps in the picture ?

[image]

EDIT:As @giobrach advised below,the condition is being mentioned.It states that partial derivative of f1 w.r.t x2 equals the partial derivative of f2 w.r.t x1.

Comment: which two steps?

Comment: the ones which involve taking derivatives w.r.t. x1 and t. Thanks.

Comment: Things don't work like that here.

Comment: That URL will disappear in time. What will this problem look like then? Either type the problem out or load an image to this site.

Comment: I'm a newbie.Sorry for not being thorough enough.Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for removing the link and helping out.

Comment: @abhibrataganguly What is condition (2) in your book? (The one that the statement of Theorem 1.4 mentions.) Please edit your question in order to include it.

Comment: @giobrach :Done, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Warning: this answer is very long, as it explains every single step in nauseating detail. Be prepared.*

That portion of the proof needs five (and a half?) major results from analysis: (a) the rule for differentiating parameter-dependent integrals with respect to a parameter, (b) the linearity of differential operators, (c) the product rule, (d) the chain rule, an important regularity result, and finally (e) the fundamental theorem of calculus.

---

**Parameter-dependent integrals.** The first rule can be stated as follows:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $K = [a,b]$ be a compact Riemann-measurable subset of $\mathbb R$ (i.e., a closed interval) and let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$; call $t$ the variable in $[a,b]$ and $\mathbf x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ the variables in $\Omega$. Let then $G$ be a continuous real function defined on $[a,b] \times \Omega$, such that its partial derivatives with respect to the $x$ variables exist and are continuous everywhere in $\Omega$ (i.e., it is of class $C^1$ with respect to the $\mathbf x$ variables). Then the function $g : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ given by
>   $$g(\mathbf x)= \int_a^b G(t,\mathbf x)\ dt, \qquad \mathbf x \in \Omega$$
>   is of class $C^1$, and its partial derivatives are given by the formula
>   $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j}(\mathbf x) = \int_a^b \frac{\partial G}{\partial x_j}(t,\mathbf x)\ dt, \qquad \mathbf x \in \Omega.$$

In the situation described by the proof, we have that $\Omega = U$ is open, and it is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, so that $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2)$; furthermore, $[a,b] = [0,1]$ (the domain of the integral that defines $F$), so that $g$ is $F$ while $G$ is given by the formula
$$G(t,x_1,x_2) = x_1 f_1(tx_1,tx_2) + x_2 f_2(tx_1,tx_2); \tag 1$$ 
now if $G$ satisfies the conditions imposed by the statement of Theorem 1, you may surely conclude that $F$ is $C^1$ and
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2) = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial G}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)\ dt = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}[x_1 f_1(tx_1,tx_2) + x_2 f_2(tx_1,tx_2) ] \ dt. \tag 2$$
But *does* $G$ satisfy these properties? This ultimately comes down to whether $f_1$ and $f_2$ do, so it depends on what properties they were defined to have by the author of your book before stating Theorem 1.4. Let's see why this is so.

---

**The linearity of differential operators.** This one is simple and intuitive:

> **Theorem 2.** Let $v, w : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable functions defined over the open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^n$, and let $a,b$ be real numbers. Then the function $c : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ defined by $c(\mathbf x) = a\cdot v(\mathbf x) + b \cdot w(\mathbf x)$ for all $\mathbf x \in \Omega$ is differentiable and its partial derivatives satisfy
>   $$\frac{\partial c}{\partial x_j}(\mathbf x) = a \cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}(\mathbf x) + b \cdot \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_j}(\mathbf x).$$

If we define two functions $v, w : [0,1] \times U \to \mathbb R$, with
$$\begin{split}
v(t,x_1,x_2) &= x_1 f_1(tx_1,tx_2), \\
w(t,x_1,x_2) &= x_2 f_2(tx_1,tx_2),
\end{split}$$
for all $t \in [0,1]$ and $(x_1,x_2) \in U$, then we may write $G = 1\cdot v + 1 \cdot w$. In the case that we also know that $v$ and $w$ are differentiable on $[0,1]\times U$, then Theorem 2 holds and $G$ is also differentiable and it satisfies

$$\begin{split}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) &= 1 \cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) + 1\cdot \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) \\ &=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(x_1 f_1(tx_1, tx_2) ) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(x_2 f_2(tx_1,tx_2)), 
\end{split}\tag 3$$

---

**The product rule.** Now, as you can see, the functions $v$ and $w$ that we find in equation $(3)$ each contain the product of two simpler functions. There is, indeed, a theorem that helps us in this situation.

> **Theorem 3.** Let $q,r : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be two differentiable functions defined on an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Then the function $p = q\cdot r : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is also differentiable and its partial derivatives obey the formula
>   $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_j}(\mathbf x) = \frac{\partial q}{\partial x_j}(\mathbf x)\ r(\mathbf x) + q(\mathbf x)\ \frac{\partial r}{\partial x_1}(\mathbf x), \qquad \forall \mathbf x \in \Omega. $$

In this case we may define four functions $q_1,r_1,q_2,r_2 : [0,1]\times U \to \mathbb R$ as
$$\begin{split}
 q_1(t,x_1,x_2) &= x_1, \\
 r_1(t,x_1,x_2) &= f_1(tx_1,tx_2), \\
 q_2(t,x_1,x_2) &= x_2, \\
 r_2(t,x_1,x_2) &= f_2(tx_1,tx_2),
\end{split}$$
so that $v = q_1 \cdot r_1$ and $w = q_2 \cdot r_2$. If we know that $q_i,r_i$ are differentiable, then Theorem 3 holds and we also know that $v$ and $w$ are, and that they satisfy
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x_1} \cdot r_1 + q_1 \cdot \frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x_1} \tag{4a}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial x_1} \cdot r_2 + q_2 \cdot \frac{\partial r_2}{\partial x_1}. \tag{4b}$$
Surely $q_1$ and $q_2$ are differentiable, and we also know their partial w.r.t. $x_1$: they are, respectively, $1$ and $0$ everywhere. The question is whether $r_1$ and $r_2$ are differentiable: to see this we need

---

**The chain rule.** This one corresponds to the following result:

> **Theorem 4.** Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\Omega'$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^k$. Let then $\mathbf s : \Omega \to \Omega'$ and $u : \Omega' \to \mathbb R$, and $h : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be the composite of $\mathbf s$ and $u$, that is, $h = u \circ \mathbf s$. If $s$ is differentiable in $\Omega$ and $u$ is differentiable in $\Omega'$, then $h$ is differentiable and it satisfies
>   $$ \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_j}(\mathbf x) = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\partial u}{\partial y_i}(\mathbf s(\mathbf x)) \cdot \frac{\partial s_i}{\partial x_j}(\mathbf x), \qquad \forall x \in \Omega.$$

Let us examine only the case of $r_1$, since the function $r_2$ behaves identically. We may define $\mathbf s : U \to  R^2$ such that
$$ \begin{split}
\mathbf s(t,x_1,x_2) &= (tx_1,tx_2),
\end{split}$$
so that indeed $r_1 = f_1(\mathbf s(t,x_1,x_2))$; in this manner, $f_1$ behaves like function $u$ from the statement, and $r_1$ like $h$. If we can show that $\mathbf s$ is differentiable and we know that $f_1$ is too, then Theorem 4 guarantees that $r_1$ is differentiable and that
$$\begin{split}
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) &= \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1}(\mathbf s(t,x_1,x_2)) \frac{\partial s_1}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_2}(\mathbf s(t,x_1,x_2)) \frac{\partial s_2}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) \\
&= \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2) \frac{\partial s_1}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_2}(tx_1,tx_2) \frac{\partial s_2}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2)
\end{split}\tag 5$$
But we *know* that $\mathbf s$ is differentiable: indeed $\mathbf s(t,x_1,x_2) = (tx_1,tx_2) = t(x_1,x_2)$, and so it satisfies
$$\begin{split}
\frac{\partial s_1}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(tx_1) = t, \\
 \frac{\partial s_2}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(tx_2) = 0.
\end{split} \tag {6}$$
The differentiability of $f_1$ instead depends on how it was defined in Question 1.1 in your book. If this definition implies the differentiability of $f_1$ then you are good to go. *Note:* it does, because in Question 1.1 it is stated that $f_1,f_2$ are equal to the partial derivatives of a smooth function, which are smooth, and so they are $C^1$, and so they are also differentiable, because of this other very important result:

> **Lemma.** Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $\chi : \Omega \to \mathbb R^m$. if $\chi$ is of class $C^1$ in $\Omega$, then it is differentiable in $\Omega$.

---

**Explaining the second equation.** Now let's piece everything together. Plugging in $(6)$ into $(5)$ you get
$$\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2) \cdot t + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_2}(tx_1,tx_2) \cdot 0 = t \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2)  \tag {7a}$$
The same, of course, applies to $r_2$:
$$\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) = \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2) \cdot t + \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_2}(tx_1,tx_2) \cdot 0 = t\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2)  \tag {7b}$$
Going back to $(4a)$ and $(4b)$, we find
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) = 1 \cdot f_1(tx_1,tx_2) + x_1 \cdot \left( t\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2) \right) \tag{8a} $$
and
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) = 0 \cdot f_1(tx_1,tx_2) + x_2 \cdot \left( t\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2) \right), \tag{8a} $$
so that, finally,
$$\begin{split}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) &= \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) + \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) \\
&= f_1(tx_1,tx_2) + tx_1\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2) + tx_2 \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2) \end{split}   \tag 9$$
But this is exactly what we find within the integral sign in the second equation of your proof! (Ignore the fact that your author is not using $y$'s where I am: he's just being notationally lazy – or I'm being pedantic.)

---

**The third equation.** Let us come to the third equation from your proof. There, we can find the *total derivative* of a function expanded by means of the very same Theorems 2, 3, and 4 that we have used above. Suppose that we want to construct a function $\varphi_{(x_1,x_2)} : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ of the variable $t$, which depends on the fixed parameters $x_1$ and $x_2$, chosen such that $(x_1,x_2) \in U$. One way to do so is to define
$$\varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}(t) = t \cdot f_1(x_1t,x_2t), \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb R. \tag{10}$$
Now, we know that since $\mathbf s$ is differentiable, then the function $\boldsymbol \sigma_{(x_1,x_2)} : t \mapsto  \boldsymbol \sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}(t) = \mathbf s(t,x_1,x_2)$ is also differentiable w.r.t. $t$ (remember: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are now fixed numbers!): its derivative is the constant vector
$$\frac{d\boldsymbol \sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}}{dt}(t) = (x_1,x_2). \tag {11} $$
Notice that we may rewrite $\varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}(t)$ as
$$\varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}(t) = t\cdot f_1(\boldsymbol \sigma(t)), \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb R; $$
since we have established that $\boldsymbol\sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}$ is differentiable, and since we know $f_1$ is as well, then $f_1 \circ \boldsymbol \sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}$ is differentiable by Theorem 4, and multiplying *it* by $t$ still produces a differentiable function by Theorem 3. Then $\varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}$ is also differentiable, and it satisfies
$$\begin{split}
\frac{d\varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}}{dt}(t) &= \frac{dt}{dt}\cdot (f_1\circ\boldsymbol\sigma_{(x_1,x_2)})(t)) + t \cdot \frac{d(f_1 \circ \boldsymbol\sigma_{(x_1,x_2)})}{dt}(t) \\
&= f_1(\boldsymbol\sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}(t)) + t\left(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1}(\boldsymbol\sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}(t)) \cdot \frac{d \sigma_{(x_1,x_2);1}}{dt}(t) + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_2}(\boldsymbol\sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}(t)) \cdot \frac{d \sigma_{(x_1,x_2);2}}{dt}(t)\right) \\
&= f_1(\boldsymbol\sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}(t)) + t\left(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1}(x_1t,x_2t) \cdot x_1 + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_2}(x_1t,x_2t) \cdot x_2\right) \\
&= f_1(x_1t,x_2t) + tx_1 \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1}(x_1t,x_2t) + tx_2 \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_2}(x_1t,x_2t)
\end{split}\tag {12}$$
where we have used the product rule at the first equal sign, the chain rule at the second (with the notation that $\sigma_{(x_1,x_2);i}$ indicates the $i$-th component function of the vector function $\boldsymbol\sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}$), equation $(11)$ at the third, and just some algebra together with the definition of $\boldsymbol \sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}$ at the fourth. You can see that this is exactly the content of the third equation in your proof!

---

**Toward the fourth equation.** Now we can see that $\partial G/\partial x_1$ (equation $(9)$) and $d\varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}/dt$ (equation $(12)$) are very similar in shape: their first two terms are identical, but the third term of $\partial G/\partial x_1$ contains the partial of $f_2$ w.r.t. $y_1$, while the third term of $d\varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}/dt$ contains the partial of $f_2$ w.r.t. $y_2$ instead. So we may say that $\partial G/\partial x_1$ is *equal* to $d\varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}/dt$ on the condition that we subtract the wrong term and add the correct one:
$$\begin{split}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_1}(t,x_1,x_2) &= \frac{d \varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}}{dt}(t) - tx_2 \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_2}(tx_1,tx_2) + tx_2 \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2) \\
&= \frac{d \varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}}{dt}(t) + tx_2 \left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}(tx_1,tx_2) - \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_2}(tx_1,tx_2)\right).
\end{split} \tag{13}$$
We may now substitute this formula into equation $(2)$ to obtain the first equal sign of the last equation in your proof. If you go back to assumption $(2)$ from your book, it states that the partial derivatives in $(13)$ cancel out, leaving just the total derivative w.r.t. $t$:
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2) = \int_0^1 \left[\frac{d \varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}}{dt}(t)\right]\ dt . \tag{14}$$
In order to proceed, we need one last piece:

---

**e. The (second) fundamental theorem of calculus.** It states

> **Theorem 5.** Let $\psi : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be of class $C^1$. Then
>   $$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \psi'(t)\ dt = \psi(t_1) - \psi(t_0), \qquad \forall t_1 \in [a,b], $$
>   and in particular
>   $$\int_a^b \psi'(t)\ dt = \psi(b) - \psi(a). $$

In our situation we have a function, $ \varphi_{(x_1,x_0)}$, that is surely $C^1$ (as we have discussed earlier), so the theorem applies with $\psi = \varphi_{(x_1,x_0)}$. Going back to $(14)$, we get:
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2) = \int_0^1 \left[\frac{d \varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}}{dt}(t)\right]\ dt = \varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}(t)\Big|_0^1. \tag{15}$$

**The home run.** By using the definition of $\varphi_{(x_1,x_2)}$ that we gave at $(10)$, we obtain from $(15)$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2) = [t f_1(tx_1,tx_2)]\Big|_0^1 = 1 \cdot f_1(1 \cdot x_1,\cdot x_2) - 0 \cdot f_1(0\cdot x_1,0\cdot x_2) = f_1(x_1,x_2). $$

Comment: Hello.Were I not an icky newbie, I would have manually posted and paid a bounty for this beautiful answer.It was very helpful and also pretty. As you said, it took a long time to read,but was too enlightening to be painful. Btw, a clarification, I see you use y's in the operators which cleans up the notation a lot.But what you denoted as y corresponds to (t.x) and not simply x. Am I  correct?

Comment: Thank you for the compliments. The variables $(t,x_1,x_2)$ range in $[0,1]\times U$, the domain of $\mathbf s$, while the variables $(y_1,y_2)$ range in the image of $\mathbf s$, so they are completely unrelated. The $\mathbf y$ variables were written $\mathbf x$ by the author because you could see $t$ as a parameter and define a new function $\mathbf s_t : (x_1,x_2) \mapsto \mathbf s(t,x_1,x_2)$ and act as though it mapped $U$ into $U$, so that the $\mathbf x$ and the $\mathbf y$ variables have "equal dignity" and may be interchanged.

Comment: Quite.And you were right, he was being notationally lazy,but that's where you came in.Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Duly noted.Thanks again(though I'll admit that this time your detailed answer fit my purpose to a tee)!

Comment: One more clarification: you can understand why confusing the $\mathbf y$'s with the $\mathbf x$'s isn't such a big deal by seeing the action of  $\mathbf s$: it takes in a point $(x_1,x_2)\in U$ and a value of $t\in [0,1]$ and outputs the point on the segment between $(0,0)$ (w.r.t. which $U$ is star-shaped, which is what allows this construction in the first place) and $(x_1,x_2)$ that lies "$t$ %" of the way between the extremes. So the image of $\boldsymbol\sigma_{(x_1,x_2)}$ is always this segment and "everything happens within $U$". Distinguishing the letters is just (useful) bookkeeping.

Comment: Glad I could help!